# Error en formulario html a php

Tags: php, html

tengo el siguiente formulario en mi pagina index.html

```
                            <form  method="post" action="correo.php">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input class="form-control" rows="3" type="text" tabindex="1"  name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Completo"  required>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <input class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Correo Electronico" type="email" tabindex="2" name="email" id="email" required>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <input class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Numero telefonico" type="telefono" tabindex="2" name="telefono" id="website" required>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea id="Message" class="form-control" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" id="template-contactform-submit" name="template-contactform-submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-blue">Enviar mensaje</button>
                                <p class="contact-send-message"></p>
                            </form>
```

y el siguiente codigó en php

```
<?php
$to      = 'mancha-94@hotmail.com;
$subject = 'Participantes';

$name   = $_POST['nombre'];     // name="name"
$email   = $_POST['email'];    // name="email"
$telefono = $_POST['telefono']
$message = $_POST['message'];  // name="message"

// Aquí compones el cuerpo del mail
$bodyMail  = "El participante de la promoción se llama {$name}".PHP_EOL;
$bodyMail  = "Su correo electronico es {$email}".PHP_EOL;
$bodyMail .= "Su web site: {$website}".PHP_EOL;
$bodyMail .= "Quiere: {$message}".PHP_EOL;
$bodyMail .= $message;

// Configurar Content-type
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8'.PHP_EOL;

// Enviado desde el email del usuario
$headers .= 'From: '.$email.PHP_EOL;


// Enviar email
if ( mail($to, $subject, $bodyMail, $headers) ) {

    $mensaje = 'Email se ha enviado con éxito.';
}
else {

    $mensaje = 'Fallo al enviar el Email.';
}
```

pero cuando lo ejecuto en mi servidor no me llega ningún correo, y me marca error http 500

como soluciono este problema?

Saludos

Comment: Estas ejecutando ese código en un servidor local (xampp, mamp)?

Comment: no en un servidor de hosting gratuito https://mex.000webhost.com/

Comment: Prueba cambiando tus headers por esto $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; y deja el que tienes de From

Comment: Aparte de algunos errores nombrados cambia también la línea `$bodyMail  =`, que tienes otro pequeño error por   `$bodyMail  .=` te falto él `.` para concatenar correctamente el cuerpo.

Comment: acabo de remplazar mis headers con los puntos que me diste, pero sigue igual :(

Answer (score 2):

Errores de sintaxis en el archivo php en:

```
$to      = 'mancha-94@hotmail.com;
```

falta cerrar comilla

```
$telefono = $_POST['telefono']
```

falta el punto y coma

Comment: ya modifique eso errores, pero mi sigue sin llegar el correo, a que se debe ?

Comment: que mensaje te envia tu script **$mensaje = 'Email se ha enviado con éxito.';** o el de fallo ?. si es el de enviado revisa tu carpeta de spam

Comment: de hecho no me arroja ningún mensaje.

Comment: Sigue marcando error 500? . ejecuta el codigo con con cadenas constantes ejemplo **$name   = 'sergio'** , agrega **error_reporting(E_ALL);** y ejecuta directamente sin pasar por el form y comenta el resultado.

Comment: ya no marca ese error, me envía al código que puse cuando se envía  el formulario, pero no me llega ningún correo, ni a no deseados (span).

Comment: Entonces el código es correcto hotmail esta filtrando tu correo. prueba con gmail u otro dominio. de hecho acabo de probar tu código y si me llego. el correo a gmail.

Comment: pregunta, esto no tendrá que ver con que use un servicio de hosting gratuito ? https://mex.000webhost.com/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67350/discussion-between-sergio-cauich-and-polo-moreno).

Comment: Prueba cambiando los headers. O utilizando phpmailer.